# Accessing rabbitmq running on local machine from docker container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, pika

I want to test a docker image running a python script subscribing to a rabbitmq queue.
I have rabbitmq running on my local machine, and want to test the docker container running on the same machine and have it subscribe to the local rabbimq server.

I want the script to read environment variables 'QUEUE_IP' set in the docker run command.

The python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

host = os.environ.get('QUEUE_IP')

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
    host=host))

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
   print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                  queue='hello',
                  no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

It doesnt work if QUEUE_IP = 127.0.0.1, and I also tried using the local ip address of the machine, but I only get

```
pika.exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError
```

Is there any easy way of accessing the local rabbitmq from the docker container ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that works is to simply add the --net=host parameter to docker run, e.g.:

```
docker run -d --net=host my/container
```

This way, the host's network is shared with the container and it can access the rabbimq server with the localhost ip (127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Docker CLI docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/):

> Sometimes you need to connect to the Docker host from within your
>   container. To enable this, pass the Docker host’s IP address to the
>   container using the --add-host flag. To find the host’s address, use
>   the `ip addr show` command.

So all you need to do is set: `QUEUE_URL` to the output of `ip addr show`.

Answer (score 1):

After trying lot of solutions, i came up with working solution.

You need to use the rabbitMQ host(mainly) in docker container where we are trying to make connection to rabbitMQ(which is locally setup)

```
host - host.docker.internal
port - 5672
user - guest (default)
password - guest (default)
```

This will save time for lot of people, i am sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Original accepted answer is already four years old, but `host.docker.internal` is the preferred way for one container to access another service or container on the same host starting docker 18.03